# Animate.css how to get it to slide in from parent container?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animate.css

I am trying to create some sort slider but could not find a slider that meets my requirement (I am willing to use one if someone can point me to something).

[image]

It is a container that will have arrow handlers(left, right) and X amount of small images, when you click on them some light box would open up to make larger. So essentially almost like thumb nails.

When you hit the arrow(I will also have auto play) the next set of images should appear. I want to slide the old set out and slide in the new set.

```
<div className="container">
    <div className="left-arrow">left arrow</div>
    <div className="item-container animated slideInRight delay-2s">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div className="right-arrow">right arrow </div>
</div>
```

Above is essentially what I have now,  I just put the slide in effect on load to see how it would look like. Now the item-container slides in but it slides in from the edge of my page instead of coming from the container.

I am using reactjs and [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css)

Comment: I think your best approach is using https://github.com/akiran/react-slick. Since you're getting lost with creating it from scratch.

Comment: I think it might be the best bet, I rather no reinvent the wheel, It does seem to meet most of my needs. Hopefully it is well maintained as seems like alot of issues are open.

Comment: It's stable. I've used it on production builds.

Comment: ok cool, I am playing around with it but it seems like the arrow disappears. https://codesandbox.io/s/4znjozz8q0